# Xgboost making bad predictions

Tags: machine-learning, python

Alright, I am training an xgboost model, that should give the probability of questions being duplicates (having the same intent). My train dataset is 70 MB; each column has a question pair and a boolean saying if the questions are duplicates (1 - duplicates, 0 - no); the set has 40% duplicates. I have a train set (x_train) that has 37% duplicates. Here are the params that I use

```
params = {}
params['objective'] = 'binary:logistic'
params['eval_metric'] = 'logloss'
params['eta'] = 0.02
params['max_depth'] = 4

d_train = xgb.DMatrix(x_train, label = y_train)
d_test = xgb.DMatrix(x_test, label = y_test)

watchlist = [(d_train, 'train'), (d_test, 'test')]
bst = xgb.train(params, d_train, 400, watchlist, early_stopping_rounds = 50)
```

The problem is : my logloss is constantly increasing, and early_stopping_rounds only works when its decreasing. In fact, when I want my model to predict something, it gives the same prediction of 0.17 for all the features

*Edit 1*:

My xgboost version is 0.40.
I am compairing the questions by how much common words they have with this formula :
 **(number of words that appear in both questions x 2) / (sum of word count of the questions)**

And how much rare words are there in the questions (I determine the rarity of a word with this formula : **(number of times the word was used in the dataset)** / **(total number of words**)
Here are some examples of rows in my x_train set:

[0.15384615384615385, 0.0075902783102047081], Duplicate

[0.42857142857142855, 1.4780520495923148], Not Duplicate

[0.16666666666666666, 0.11852563542667481], Duplicate

[0.3333333333333333, 0.68822955503676098], Not Duplicate

[0.3333333333333333, 0.13004646236067308] Not Duplicate

Comment: Are your `y` labels 0 and 1?

Comment: It's impossible to help you without a reproducible example. Can you at least post a few sample rows of your features, along with the duplicates indicator?

Comment: @MatthewDrury Yes, they are

Comment: @Philippe can you please clarify "comparing the questions by how much common words they have"- does this mean words that are in each question, or words that occur frequently in the dataset?

Comment: @ThomasCleberg I compare by common words with this fromula   :              (2 * number of words that appear in both questions) / (sum of word count of the questions)

Comment: Thank you. Can you please confirm whether XGBoost is getting one feature that is an array of shape [1,2] or two separate features?

Comment: @ThomasCleberg The xgboost.train() method receives an array with the two features I described in my question (common words and word rarity)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're working on the Kaggle.com [Quora Question Pairs](https://www.kaggle.com/c/quora-question-pairs) problem.

In this problem, question1 and question2, the question titles to be compared, are stored as text strings. These strings are very unlikely to be duplicated exactly in the remainder of the dataset. XGBoost is going to interpret this as (more or less) two levels of factors that have *only* unique values and thus hold no useful information- no general knowledge of the problem can be generated from any individual row, nor any combination of rows.

The center of the problem is *how to generate useful metrics from the question texts such that they can be compared*. Some possible features, such as the number or percent of repeated words across questions 1 and 2 or the [Levenshtein distance](https://people.cs.pitt.edu/~kirk/cs1501/Pruhs/Spring2006/assignments/editdistance/Levenshtein%20Distance.htm) between them may, on the other hand, be extremely useful for predicting whether the question is duplicated between the questions based on the title.

Basically, XGBoost has no idea what you want it to do with the text data in the factors in question- you have to add value by providing data that XGBoost can use.

By the way, the prediction of 0.17 is merely the prior of the training dataset- that is, the proportion of duplicates that exist in that data. It's effectively saying that the algorithm has no extra information except for the count of positive and negative class examples to go by.

Comment: Actually, x_train is a 2D array of features that I used. I am comparing them by word_match_share and the number of rare words contained in each of them (my features are actually a bit more complex, but you got the idea).

Comment: >By the way, the prediction of 0.17 is merely the prior of the training dataset- that is, the proportion of duplicates that exist in that data.                             My train set has 37% duplicates...

Comment: Yes, that's right. Can you please post your full working code so that we can troubleshoot further? The common words feature appears to have some valuable predictive power by itself- I can't tell where it's going wrong for you without seeing all of the code.